# How do I find other kids ages 12-14 to play Dungeons and Dragons with

Tags: dnd-5e

I have been trying to find sites online, like https://www.meetup.com/topics/dnd/ to find kids around my age to play d&d with, and that would mostly have a general idea of the game and rules, but no results.  One of the biggest issues is that I live in clarksville, and there aren't many people that are interested, while in a place like Nashville, several tabletop RPG group would let someone join with open arms.  The second biggest issue is that most friends and family would rather use their time playing fortnite and other video games and not take the time for what they think of a stupid and nerdy games that only losers play (except my father). I hope that the internet will have the answer, and know my fate depends on YOU.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of our big "how to find gamers" question - I think you'll find all those tips apply to you (I was in your position in Memphis back in 1993, and had several gamer friends from Clarksville).  Post at Frontline Games, start a D&D club at school, go to nearby conventions (TennCon in Knoxville was big back then, I know it's gone but I'm sure there's something else)... Just adapt each of those tips to your location.

Comment: @mxyzplk I love the idea of trying to create a club at school and will definitely look into some conventions I can find near clarksville, but I don't know how to post at frontline games,but thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: It's a local game store - you'd go there and ask the clerk if they have a (physical) bulletin board or the like, or if there's play space try to meet people there.

Comment: you are the best @mxyzplk, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Frontline Games also has D&D Adventure League on Wednesday nights at 6pm. I only know that from looking at their event calendar. I don't know much about AL, I don't know if there's an age limit. As mxyzplk said, they may have a bulletin board or similar.

Comment: I found the date and time for AL, but your right @Jack, my age might hinder my ability to play, but hopefully my father will join me in the clashing of steel,so I don't play with men in their 20's alone.  maybe there shall be a young man or woman there to accompany me.

Comment: Feel free to join us in [chat] if you have any other questions or comments!